# How to write a generic java method to return value with null check?

Tags: java, methods, java-8, polymorphism

I have some code which copies values from one object to another.

When I have to null check values my code becomes very lengthy and harder to read, so I want a method that gets the instance of the object and returnd the value I need with a null check.

Is there a way to make such a method?

My usages are similar to the following:

```
    objectInstance.setName(methodNullCheck(object.getName()));
    
    objectInstance.setAddress(methodNullCheck(object.getAddress().getFullAddress));
```

My intention is to have a function that could have a NullPointerException check on the input parameter and return the value if it exists.

How do I write such a method?

Comment: You can't do it generically; but you could do it with `Optional`, perhaps: `Optional.ofNullable(object).map(Object::getName).ifPresent(objectInstance::setName);`?

Comment: If you have a method returning something just make it return Optional.of(<your object>). This forces the user who is calling the method to handle if the the thing being returned is null or not.

Comment: What if it's null? What do you expect to return?

Comment: @Tanimak the value it self

Comment: @roeygol I think if you can post part of the messy code that will be helpful to understand your requirement better.

Comment: @Tanimak messy code is when im using canonical condition check of the object, Im trying to avoid this kind of code

Comment: Looks to me like you are trying to check null, handle exceptions and also control data based on the error scenarios. Is that correct? secondly what if `object.getAddress()` is null? You will not be able to catch that exception this way.

Comment: Do you mean something like: `return someString != null ? someString : null`? That just defeats the purpose of the null check. `return someString != null ? someString : ""` could return empty string instead, can you post your code?

Comment: @DustinR no I can't post my code, but your example is what I need, but it should be a solution for any kind of null

Comment: If you want to throw an NPE, use `Objects.requireNonNull()`, else use `Optional.ofNullable()`. Optional doesn't really help if the value is vital, but requireNonNull is essentially a concise null check, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code:

```
   public <T> T methodNullCheck(T value) {
        if (value != null) {
            return value;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null value");
        }
    }
```

I would suggest to use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) and `@NonNull` annotation on input parameters of `setName()`, `setAddress()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a null safe Function

```
interface NullSafeFunction<T, R> extends Function<T, R> {

    default <V> NullSafeFunction<T, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
        return (T t) -> Optional.ofNullable(t).map(this::apply).map(after).orElse(null);
    }

    static <T> NullSafeFunction<T, T> identity() {
        return t -> t;
    }
}
```

and then use it as follows

```
A a1 = new A();

String result1 = NullSafeFunction.<A>identity()
        .andThen(A::getB)
        .andThen(B::getC)
        .andThen(C::getD)
        .apply(a1);

System.out.println(result1); //null

A a2 = new A(new B(new C("yes")));

String result2 = NullSafeFunction.<A>identity()
        .andThen(A::getB)
        .andThen(B::getC)
        .andThen(C::getD)
        .apply(a2);

System.out.println(result2); //yes
```